# Select value and populate data into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d904amng/  (No the way that i wanted)

```js
$("#counties").click(function(){
    var selectedValues = [];    
    $("#counties :selected").each(function(){
        selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
    });
   $("#email").val(selectedValues);
});

function setMail(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>    
  Email:
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  Counties:
  <br>
  <select id="counties" onClick="return setMail()" >
    <option data-mail="1" value="Choose One">Choose One</option>
    <option data-mail="2" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
    <option data-mail="3" value="Collier">Collier</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

What I wanted:

1. When user click on "Charlotte" it will populate "Charlotte" to the
   textarea
2. After that, the user select "Collier" it will populate "Collier" behind
   "Charlotte Text"

How it will look like after select both of them

> Textarea: Charlotte, Collier

Comment: Declare `selectedValues` outside your `click` event and check if the selected `counties` already exist in `selectedValues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues in your code:

1. On each event your a new array is created (`selectedValues`).  You have to declare `selectedValues` outside of the event handler function.
2. You can also check whether the item is present in the array or not.
3. You can think of *change* event instead of *click* here.
4. As only one option can be selected at a time you do not need `.each()` to loop through the selected option as this is meaningless.

```js
var selectedValues = []; 
$("#counties").change(function(){
  if(!selectedValues.includes($(this).val()) && $(this)[0].selectedIndex != 0)
    selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
  $("#email").val(selectedValues.join('\n'));
})

function setMail(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>    
  Email:
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  Counties:
  <br>
  <select id="counties" onClick="return setMail()" >
    <option data-mail="1" value="Choose One">Choose One</option>
    <option data-mail="2" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
    <option data-mail="3" value="Collier">Collier</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Updated as mentioned in the comment:

```js
var selectedValues = []; 
$("#counties").click(function(){
  if($(this)[0].selectedIndex != 0)
    selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
  $("#email").val(selectedValues.join('\n'));
})

function setMail(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>    
  Email:
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  Counties:
  <br>
  <select id="counties" onClick="return setMail()" multiple>
    <option data-mail="1" value="Choose One">Choose One</option>
    <option data-mail="2" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
    <option data-mail="3" value="Collier">Collier</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The code work fine , but it is possible to make multiple ? Example : able to select Collier multiple times . Example : Select 3x times "Collier" In TextArea: Collier,Collier,Collier

Comment: @incognitorecon, please see the second answer (adding multiple attribute in select and click event)

Comment: i see, thanks for the help. I wondered that is it possible to change the output ? or "," is fixed ?
it's optional , but just wanted to get more knowledge on this, like example , when selecting 3x time of "Collier" , i want it to show output on : Collier <br> Collier <br> Collier .   In other word , the result return in a new line instead of using "," and show beside.

Comment: @incognitorecon, yes it is simple, just join the array values with `\n` like `$("#email").val(selectedValues.join('\n'));`:)

Comment: @incognitorecon, you are most welcome. Updated the answer thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change()` and directly push value to `selectedValues[]` rather than looping using `each()`.

Further, giving empty value as `value=""` can also be useful since you do not want `Choose One` in your `textarea`

```js
var selectedValues = [];
$("#counties").change(function() {
  if (!selectedValues.includes($(this).val()) && $(this).val())
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  $("#email").val(selectedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Email:
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <br> Counties:
  <br>
  <select id="counties">
    <option data-mail="1" value="">Choose One</option>
    <option data-mail="2" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
    <option data-mail="3" value="Collier">Collier</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Multiple**

```js
var selectedValues = [];
$("#counties").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val())
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  $("#email").val(selectedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Email:
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <br> Counties:
  <br>
  <select id="counties">
    <option data-mail="1" value="">Choose One</option>
    <option data-mail="2" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
    <option data-mail="3" value="Collier">Collier</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The code work fine , but it is possible to make multiple ?

Example : able to select Collier multiple times . 

Example : Select 3x times "Collier"

In TextArea: Collier,Collier,Collier

Comment: sure, just remove the if condition. Have edited the post